# Google reCaptcha in Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, recaptcha

I have a Master page and some Content pages (Home, Contact, About Us, Store, etc)

My question is: 
-If I add an invisible reCaptcha v.3 from Google to the Master page, it will protect all my content pages ?

-It is a good practice to add to Master Page or just for pages like: login, register?

Thanks advanced

(The website is written in asp.net 3.5 web-forms. )

Answer (score 0):

If the reCaptcha requires server side code and is not required on every page, stick it in a [user control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8) (.ascx file). Then reference this file on any pages that actually need it. Putting unnecessary code in a master page is not a good practice as it can lead to confusion (what does this code do?/why is it here?) and can potentially conflict with other code on your page.

Comment: in short: I'm using a WebMethod (CaptchaVerify) to deserialize the JSON results and another function (RecaptchaVerify) to get the response string. The WebMethod is calling the function for response string. <br/> Now I'm only using in the registration form.

Comment: Not putting reCaptcha into master pages makes sense. How is putting reCaptcha into a user control better than directly into individual content pages?